# Make online payments anonymously?

Tags: anonymity, credit-card, e-commerce

Is there a **service**/company which allows you to make anonymous payments online ?

This is how i want the service to work - Just like a credit/debit card. When you make the payment online, instead of entering your real name and real address, you enter the name-code and address-code issued to you by the **service**. To the receiver of the payment, it should appear as if the payment came from the **service** and not you.

If such a service does not exist, then is there any similar alternative ? I had a quick look at escrow. But not sure if enables one to pay anonymously.

Why I want this service ? 
I think that the receiver of my payment gets to see my personal info when i enter it in their website to make a payment. I don't want that to happen.

**END OF QUESTION.**

As an aside, we can have some features -

If the receiver has some genuine legal reasons to request for the real name and address, the **service** should allow him to find the real person behind the codes. Once the real info of a person is revealed to the receiver and courts determine that he has done nothing illegal, then this person receives a new code.

Comment: That would be money laundering then. (the 'genuine legal reasons' thing doesn't work very well in practice).

Answer (score 6):

Bitcoins, and merchants which accept them, are inherently anonymous. It isn't exactly what you want, but it is an anonymous currency.

Comment: Not quite true. :) http://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2013/04/zerocoin-making-bitcoin-anonymous.html

Comment: But how many merchants really accept them ?

Answer (score 6):

Look into something called a [virtual credit card](http://www.creditcards.com/credit-card-news/virtual-disposable-one-time-credit_card-numbers-1273.php). Basically, it's temporarily linked to your real number for one transaction, or until you cancel it. Once it is cancelled it cannot be traced (or shouldn't be able to, without sufficient cause. If you're commiting fraud or something, however, I imagine that can be traced back if reported to your credit company) back to your real card.

Additional info:

- http://ptmoney.com/shop-safely-online-use-a-virtual-credit-card-number/
- http://money.usnews.com/money/personal-finance/articles/2011/09/30/should-you-use-a-virtual-credit-card-number

Comment: Thanks for the links. I am still reading them, but I have not come across any information about the Name and address issue. If I use such cards, will i have to enter my real name and address to make an online payment ?

Answer (score 1):

Bit Coins are definetly the way to go. And Bit Coins are also huge comodity these days. Something to definetly look into for both anonymous online sales, purchases, and investing.

https://bitpay.com/bitcoin-shopping-cart-plugins

Comment: Investing? Speculating maybe, but not investing.

Comment: @DodgyG33za Well I see where your coming from. But to my understanding their will only be a certain amount ever made. The worth seem to be going up more then they are going down.

Answer (score 1):

If it's going to be used to pay for services online that will not connect back to you, then you can use a prepaid credit card and a fake name. Then reload the prepaid card to make future payments. Some accounts like a [prepaid Visa Card](http://usa.visa.com/personal/cards/prepaid/prepaid-card-faq.html) allow you to transfer funds to the card at set intervals. You can also use the Visa Gift cards online (they'll give you a pin once you register the card).

In regard to getting paid anonymously:

I had a client that was concerned about sharing their info, so they sent me a prepaid credit card through the mail, to me, from me, and they would reload the card, then I would do the work once I had the money. The card did not have my name on it, or theirs. I was able to pull cash directly off of the card at ATMs (although it looks suspicious if you go around hitting every ATM in the area because you're exceeding the ATM limits).

Check the card fine print to see if there is a daily spending limit. Also some cards have reload limits.